# Can you have a leading quartic gauge vertex in the standard model?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, elementary-particles

Under the standard model, is it possible to have a leading quartic gauge vertex in a reaction? For example, if I have a proton collider to look for the reaction $p\bar{p}\to q\bar{q}g$ (may not actually be observable with the free gluon, but just an example), would the following Feynman diagram be permissible under the standard model?

[image]

In the literature, I normally see 4-vertex couplings used to correct calculations at higher orders as opposed to them being used in leading order. My question is the same for electroweak gauge bosons, just using gluons as an example.

Comment: Note that there are trees with 2 cubic gluon vertices at the same leading order in the coupling constant.